# Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column nodejs

Tags: node.js

Im a newbie programmer and im working on a project with a login system. Im trying to get password changing working but getting this error: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '$2b$10$df6we4GJENF9t7xVTwFSu.H5.jBOX5lGc0NSErOrGV2NYIf2Dt3Ki' in 'field list'. (Thats the hashed password i want to store to mySQL)

Here is my update statement:

```
 let query3 = 'UPDATE users SET `password`='+hash+' WHERE id='+id+';';
```

It works if i just say SET 'password'="asd" manually but its not working with the +hash+

Comment: better to use some orm like sequlize

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the string interpolation. I suggest you use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for this which is nice and neat.

Template literals start with a backtick can contain placeholders that are indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces `${}`

Snippet to demo:

```js
let hash = 'password';
let id = 'dude';

let query = `UPDATE users SET password = "${hash}" WHERE id = "${id}";`;

console.log(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around the hash.

```
 let query3 = 'UPDATE users SET `password`="'+hash+'" WHERE id='+id+';';
```

Comment: Ahhh sweet it was that simple. Thank you kind stranger!